# SVN relocate issue with uuid

Tags: svn, working-copy, svn-switch

I have a question about `svn switch --relocate`. I have an old repository called `beta` and we are moving to a new SVN server. There I created a new repo called `legacy` and committed all the files from the `beta` repository. Now I need to update all the working copies to use the repo `legacy`. When I do a command for this, it says the UUID doesn't match:

```
svn switch --relocate file:///var/www/svn/beta https://domain.com/svn/legacy

svn: The repository at 'https://domain.com/svn/legacy' has uuid '3e359681-0317-844a-a84c-80a4a624e59d', but the WC has '35afee29-560b-4976-914e-5bafcd58a7c0'
```

How can I fix it so that the working copy is connected to the legacy repo?

Comment: Check out a fresh WC instead? It's usually easier in the long run.

Comment: Loading an actual dump of `beta` into `legacy` instead of a 'new commit' normally also sets the uuid, and as a bonus lets you keep all history.

Answer (score 2):

You can't switch between repositories, if they have different UUID (they are "unrelated"). You have to make

- new fresh checkout from `legacy`

or

- [setuuid](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html) legacy for using UUID of beta

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found that works is (and this will eliminate your history)

1. Delete the .svn folder in the root of your project
2. Check it in to the new repo.

No amount of fiddling with the UUIDs helped me.